# Pass parameters to an application

Tags: syntax, vbscript, command-line-arguments

I'm attempting to use ghostscript to set a specific page size for scanned PDF files.  I can run the script when it resides in the same folder as the executable but when I move the .vbs file out of the directory I can't get it to work.  The .run line is where I'm having problems.  The triple quotes for exe path without arguments opens the exe but i can't figure out how to pass the parameters.
I'm sure you can see that I'm pretty new to this.

```
strInput = InputBox ("Enter 1 for Landscape or 2 for portrait:")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If strInput=1 then  
    Call LandScape 
ElseIf strInput=2 Then
    Call Portrait
Else
    MsgBox "Your entry is invalid.  Click OK to exit"
End If
```

Landscape sub-routine:

```
Sub LandScape
    MsgBox "Your images are Landscape"
    objShell.Run """c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.04\bin\gswin64c.exe""& "-dQUIET"&" -dNOPAUSE"&" -dBATCH"&" -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=2592"&" -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1728"&" -dFIXEDMEDIA"&" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite"&" -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf"&" INPUT.pdf""

    'This line works when in same directory: gswin64c -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=2592 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1728 -dFIXEDMEDIA -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf INPUT.pdf
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you have each of your arguments separated with the &?  Those are not necessary in this case.

Comment: I've tried without them.  I've tried it with them.  I've change quotes.  I've added commas...  I may have missed some things I've tried in there..  :)

Comment: They don't hurt functionality wise, but it definitely makes it less easy to read.  Is it successfully calling GhostScript from your script just not passing in the parameters?  What is your actual problem?

Comment: Quotes were the issue.  I thought I had tried all combinations but apparently not.  This worked:

Comment: objShell.Run """c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.04\bin\gswin64c.exe"" -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=2592 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1728 -dFIXEDMEDIA -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf INPUT.pdf"""

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Adding all of those extra "&" can definitely clutter your code and make it difficult to debug.  It looks like in your original command, you just had an extra " after `gswin64c.exe`

Answer (score 0):

The 1st parameter to [`WScript.Shell.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is a full command line. So you need to

1. Add spaces between arguments;
2. Quote arguments that contain embedded spaces. In VB/VBScript, two consecutive double quotes inside a string literal are interpreted as a literal quote.

Can you now deduce the correct syntax for the `objShell.Run` line?

Answer (score 0):

The quotes can get confusing so it sometimes helps to use `Chr(34)` instead and to keep the executable separate from its params.

```
strExe    = "c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.04\bin\gswin64c.exe"
strParams = "-dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=2592 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1728 -dFIXEDMEDIA -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf INPUT.pdf"

objShell.Run Chr(34) & strExe & Chr(34) & " " & strParams
```