# shell script not workig with parameters

Tags: shell, vbscript, parameters, winrar

This works with CMD:

```
rar a c:\new.rar c:\*.*
```

This works running script.vbs, but does not do too much!:

```
Function qq(strIn)
    qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
    End Function
    Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyCmd = "Cmd /c CD /D " & qq("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR") & " & a c:\new.rar c:\*.* "

sh.run MyCmd,1,True
```

It is no longer returning errors, but file new.rar is not being created either, it says 'a' is not a valid parameter

Answer (score 1):

(1) Always echo the command before you try to feed it to run:

```
>> MyCmd = "Cmd /c CD /D " & qq("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR") & " & a c:\new.rar c:\*.* "
>> WScript.Echo MyCmd
>>
Cmd /c CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR" & a c:\new.rar c:\*.*
```

Obviously your concatenation puts a spurious "&" in the result.

(2) Never let you be persuaded to put random additions like "cmd /c cd /d" into you command.

(3) Build your command line in a structured way. E.g:

```
Option Explicit
Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function
Dim sCmd  : sCmd  = Join(Array( _
     qq("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR") _
   , "a" _
   , qq("c:\some path with spaces\new.rar") _
   , qq("c:\source dir with more spaces\*.*") _
))
WScript.Echo sCmd
```

output:

```
cscript y.vbs
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR" a "c:\some path with spaces\new.rar" "c:\source dir with more spaces\*.*"
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25093273/603855) for background and reasons why.

**Update:**

This way, blunders (just the path, not the full filespec of rar mentioned) can be spotted and corrected easily:

```
Option Explicit
Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function
Dim sCmd  : sCmd  = Join(Array( _
     qq("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\rar.exe") _
   , "a" _
   , qq("c:\some path with spaces\new.rar") _
   , qq("c:\source dir with more spaces\*.*") _
))
WScript.Echo sCmd
```

Comment: echo, of course!, thanks for tips ,  code works great, never seen so many quotations, will vote up as soon as I get my rank! such a newb,This is my first script! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code and let me know if it works or not for you ?

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyCmd = "Cmd /c CD /D " & qq("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR") & " & rar /? & pause"
sh.run MyCmd,1,True
'************************************
Function qq(strIn)
qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
End Function
'************************************
```

**EDIT :** Check this code :

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyCmd = "Cmd /c CD /D " & qq("C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR") & " & rar a c:\new.rar c:\*.* & pause"
sh.run MyCmd,1,True
'************************************
Function qq(strIn)
qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
End Function
'************************************
```

Comment: Show us how you tried it with you parameters ? by editing your first post

Comment: Thanks, your function worked for pausing, but see above, also thanks, I did not know that i should edit first post

Comment: Ok Check my edit and if it works don't forget to vote and accept it ;)

Comment: At least print your result before posting. You qout the path!

Comment: @ Ekkehard.Horner Why you downvote on my code it works for me ?? i reply just what he expected as aim !!